# Azure DNS and GoDaddy

Tags: azure, dns

I have an Azure website at `docketsweep.azurewebsites.net` and a domain on GoDaddy for `docketsweep.com`

So I want to use my `docketsweep.com` domain to handle `docketsweep.azurewebsites.net`. I have followed Azure's instructions and set up

- A CNAME pointing to awverify.docketsweep.azurewebsites.net
- A record point to 168.62.180.173

The custom domain works but when you go to `docketsweep.com` it loads docketsweep.azurewebsites.net in the URL bar. I ideally want:

```
docketsweep.com/example
```

Rather than:

```
docketsweep.azurewebsites.net/example
```

How would I change the URL it uses?

Comment: This does not really belong on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by this URL https://docketsweep.azurewebsites.net/license.txt you're running WordPress. WordPress rewrites the URL on the fly with whatever is defined as home domain.

So change that to **domain.com** instead of **domain.azurewebsites.net** and it will work.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

> **Settings > General screen > WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)**

or

> **wp-config.php**
>
> ```
> define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
> define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
> ```